# How to select the element by VBA IE automation

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation, ie-automation

I am not able to select the following text field using VBA

Please help

Html code

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="new-password" name="confirm bank loan account Number" placeholder="************" class="form-control" value="">@
```

My code

```
IE.document.getelementsbyname("confirm bank loan account Number").Value = "4546466464"
```

Comment: <input type="text" autocomplete="new-password" name="confirm bank loan account Number" placeholder="************" class="form-control" value="">

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a collection of elements (even if it's just one, you still have to access the item by it's index)

Comment: Note: If there are no elements found that match, `getElementsByName` will return `Nothing` so make sure to check that condition before you try to access its `.Value` (Don't try to do it all in one line like so many websites tell you to do)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion given by NickSlash.

You need to pass the index number like below when you access the elements using `getElementsByname` because there could be many elements on the page with the same name. `getElementsByname` returns the collection.

`IE.document.getElementsByName("confirm bank loan account Number")(0).Value = "4546466464"`

Output:

[image]